# MongoDB decrement until zero

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to achieve an operation in MongoDB that would be analogous to `doc.value = max(doc.value - amount, 0)`. I could do it by fetching document, updating its value then saving it, but is it possible with an atomic operation to avoid problems with synchronisation of parallel decrements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, in fact, possible to achieve with a single operation. All you need is an aggregation pipeline inside an update operator.

Let's say you have a doc that looks like this:

```
{
    "key": 1,
    value: 30
}
```

You want to subtract x from `value` and if the resulting value is less than zero, set `value` to 0, otherwise set it to whatever `value` - x is. Here is an update aggregator you need. In this example I am subtracting 20 from `value`.

```
db.collection.update({
  key: 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "value": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $subtract: [
                  "$value",
                  20
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$value",
              20
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be:

```
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 10
  }
```

But if you change 20 to, say 44, the result is:

```
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 0
  }
```

Here is a Playground for you: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y9yO6v9Oca8

Comment: i got an error: Wrong type for 'u'. Expected a object, got a array.

Answer (score 3):

Kudos to [codemonkey's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168038/5099971) for providing a solution using aggregation pipelines for an atomic transaction.

Here's a slightly simpler aggregation pipeline that takes advantage of the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "value": {
        $max: [
          0,
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$value",
              20
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

The pipeline sets the value to the maximum of 0 and the result of the decrement.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/REuAIlBiKlH)