# MongoDB - Decrement a certain value in a nested object, but dont let it go below 0

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongooseSchema (simplified):

```
_id: (ObjectId)
storage: [
    {
        location: String
        storedFood:[
            {
             "name": String
             "code": String
             "weight": Number
            }
        ]     
    }
]
```

I want to dec the weight, but not below 0. [There is a stackoverflow answer that does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167710/mongodb-decrement-until-zero)(The second answer from @rpatel). Great! The problem here is that he uses a update-pipeline WITHOUT nested documents. I didnt find a source where I could learn something about mongdob pipelines and nested object (If you have any please let me know, I really want to learn complex pipelines)

Is someone here who could adapt the following code to decrement `weight`,where `location` equals for example "Dubai" and `code` equals for example "38102371982" ?

Code from @rpatel:

[Mongo-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHuTiZp-KQ6)

Example-Document:

```
{
    "key": 1,
    value: 30
}
```

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "value": {
        $max: [
          0,
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$value",
              20
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[A ready playground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oBhhQTf0OhF)

Comment: Which nested object you want to decrement?

Comment: I want to decrement the `weight`. I edited the question too ty.

Comment: Yes, but you have to specify which `weight` you want to update? For example: the `weight` with the object of "storedFood.name": "Pepsi" in  "location": "Home" array. Or all the weight for "location": "Home" array? Or you want to decrement all the `weight`. Need for clarify before provide the answer.

Comment: Misunderstanding mb. I want to decrement the `weight`, where `location === "Dubai"` and `code==="38102371982"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use double `$map` with `$cond` in order to get into the double nested array item:

```
db.collection.update(
  {storage: {$elemMatch: {location: wantedLoc}}},
  [{$set: {
      storage: {
        $map: {
          input: "$storage",
          as: "st",
          in: {$cond: [
              {$eq: ["$$st.location", wantedLoc]},
              {location: "$$st.location",
                storedFood: {$map: {
                    input: "$$st.storedFood",
                    in: {$cond: [
                        {$eq: ["$$this.code", wantedCode]},
                        {$mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this", 
                          {weight: {$max: [0, {$subtract: ["$$this.weight", reduceBy]}]}}
                        ]},
                        "$$this"
                    ]}
                  }
                }
              },
              "$$st"
          ]}
        }
      }
  }}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k_kZHJXmx1L)

Comment: It works! Do you have a good source to learn these type of pipelines? I have only found tutorials or documentation about toplevel pipelines but nothing that goes really deep into this topic and nested level.

Comment: I use the the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)